# Web api project on one port and Front end

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, .net

I have 2 project in 1 visual studio solution - Front end(HTML, CSS and JS) and Web API.They are running on separated ports - the FE on 37056 and API on 6596.In the JS files im targeting the wep api controllers - for example http://localhost:6596/api/Contacts/GetContacts, and the rendering the response from the Wep API on the HTML page.So far so good..

Here is come the problem - in the HTML the URLs are presented http://localhost:37056/about.html, so if for example i want to point to some specific resource returned by the Web API this is not possible.If i type for example http://localhost:37056/api/Contacts/GetContacts there will be wrong request.

How i can to bypass this - i have a blog post in the Front end that are feed with data from WEB api + database.I want to give the user opportunity to http://localhost:37056/api/Blog/Page=1 at the moment this is only possible if he/she navigate to the page called Blog in the Front end and click on specific Post and the URL in the browser will Not change.It will be  http://localhost:37056/api/Blog without page numbers and so on (JS is making the requests).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're concatenating FrontEnd URL (http://localhost:37056) with the BackEnd resource (api/Contacts/GetContacts).

There are two ways to solve this:

- Return from BackEnd absolute URL (instead relative) pointing to backend resource. This should be feasible, since backend "knows" it's own URL.
- Store in FrontEnd base URL from backend, and concatenate it to relative paths returned.

I suggest using first option, because in case some resources are moved to a new location (for example, external resources stored in third-party servers) you don't need to update front end at all.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use absolute uri instead of relative Uri in html?